# The RabbitMQ broker doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

When I try to start my `RabbitMQ` I get this error message:

> rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code)
>   since Sun 2019-01-06 15:44:20 MSK; 10ms ago   Process: 4579
>   ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited,
>   status=127)  Main PID: 4579 (code=exited, status=127)

I tried different versions and I keep get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**: After finding other potential solutions via Internet searches, none of them worked for my issue and perhaps the one originally listed above. The error reports not being able to start rabittmq on host. After days of researching and trying different suggestions, my fix is shared below:

**FIX**: Add hostname of system to the hosts file using **nano /etc/hosts**.

**EXAMPLE**: 192.168.1.100 server.domain.lan server

========================================================================

As added info, experiencing the same issue with CentOS76 installation. I have attempted installation on CentOS74 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as well using **systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service** Interestingly enough, there are no logs available in /var/log/rabbitmq. If I am not mistaken, on CentOS I sourced the rabbitmq from the epel-release repository using yum install rabbitmq-server. I have yet to locate/discover a solution. Hoping someone has found a solution and willing to share.

```
systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Got notification message from PID 10816, but         reception only p...D 10799
rabbitmq-server[10799]: ERROR: epmd error for host office: timeout (timed out)
rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
rabbitmqctl[10829]: Stopping and halting node rabbit@office ...
rabbitmqctl[10829]: Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@office: nodedown
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: **rabbitmq-server.service failed**.
```